# ¿Como puedo hacer una mezcla de colores susctractiva mediante operadores de bit en c?

Tags: c

Tengo que realizar una función donde me dan por argumentos 2 colores y yo tengo que devolver un uchar de de la mezcla de colores sustractivos.Todo por operador de bits y en ansi.

/*codigo*/
`uchar mezclar_colores(uint colora,uint colorb){
return (uchar)((colora & colorb));
}`

Comment: Hola. ¿Cual es la pregunta? Entiendo que la función ya la tienes resuelta y funcionando, y que los tipos uchar y uint corresponden a unsigned char e int respectivamente, Aclara la pregunta y añade algo más de código si lo ves necesario para esa aclaración.

Answer (score 2):

Una mezcla sustractiva, según tengo entendido, es aquella en la que los colores para formar el negro (a diferencia de la aditiva, donde los colores se mezclan para formar el blanco).
Por tanto, debes sumar los valores de los colores para las componentes del color.

En este sentido, la operación que has hecho no está bien. Has puesto `a & b`, que no es el operador que más nos interesa.

En primer lugar, debes saber que hay una relación entre los operadores a nivel de bit, los lógicos y los operadores aritméticos: una suma aritmética (`+`) se parece bastante a una disyunción lógica (`or`). Es más, en el campo de la lógica, al operador `or` se le llama suma lógica. Y a nivel de bit, una suma lógica se parece al operador `or`.

Dicho esto, lo más parecido a una suma aritmética, es una suma lógica a nivel de bit (`a | b`).

El problema es que pierdes el acarreo al realizar esta suma.

Pongámonos en el caso de querer sumar 126 y 1, con la suma lógica bit a bit. Y supongamos para ello números sin signo de 1 Byte de ancho.

```
126 = 0111 1110
001 = 0000 0001
--------------- OR (|)
127 = 0111 1111
```

La operación se realiza correctamente porque el `o` a nivel de bit lo que hace es poner a `1` el bit correspondiente cuando uno o los dos bits de los operandos son `1`. En cierta forma se está sumando cada par de bits.

Ahora bien, tomando el ejemplo de sumar 127 y 1.

```
127 = 0111 1111
001 = 0000 0001
--------------- OR (|)
127 = 0111 1111
```

El número se queda igual, es decir, la suma con el operador `|` no ha funcionado porque descarta el acarreo.

Teniendo esto como base, podemos imaginarnos que se puede sumar dos números con este operador, pero calculando manualmente el acarreo que nos llevamos a la siguiente cifra.

De hecho, el acarreo serán aquellos bits que coincidan  en los dos sumandos, lo que podemos conseguir con la multiplicación lógica a nivel de bit (`&`).

```
127 = 0111 1111
001 = 0000 0001
--------------- AND (&)
001 = 0000 0001
```

Una vez calculado, nos lo llevamos hacia el siguiente par de bits, como lo haríamos al sumar en el colegio con "llevadas" o acarreo.

```
001 = 0000 0001
--------------- DESPL. (<<)
002 = 0000 0010
```

Y repetimos el proceso: el número que resultaba de sumar los originales lo sumamos con el acarreo tras desplazarlo a la izquierda, y al mismo tiempo calculamos un nuevo acarreo.

En realidad, nos estamos llevando lo que sobra de la suma hacia la izquierda.

El código queda así:

```
unsigned sumaConOperadoresDeBit(unsigned numero, unsigned sumando)
{
    unsigned acarreo = sumando;
    unsigned nuevoNumero, nuevoAcarreo;

    while (true)
    {
        nuevoNumero = numero | acarreo;
        nuevoAcarreo = numero & acarreo;
        numero = nuevoNumero;
        acarreo = nuevoAcarreo;
    if (acarreo == 0) break;
        acarreo<<1;
    }
}

return numero;
```

Este código funciona para números sin signo, para evitar desbordamientos que provoquen números negativos muy grandes.

Esta operación la deberías realizar con cada componente de cada color, es decir, byte a byte de los colores originales. Por lo que solo te quedaría separar `colora` y `colorb` en los bytes que las componen (y ajustar los tipos de la función que las suma).